# Grails findAll closure combine query with hasmany field

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, findall

As per the below Domain Classes

```
VisitSchedules{
    Visit visit
    static hasMany = [users: User]
    ...
}

Visit{
    DateTime startTime
    ...
}
```

I want to query VisitSchedules for visits that are scheduled for a future date for the user.
something like below

```
def upcomingVisitSchedules = VisitSchedules.findAll {
    visit.startTime >= new DateTime() && users.contains(user)//How do I query if the users list contains the current user?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and... Construction VisitSchedules.findAll, VisitSchedules.where and VisitSchedules.withCriteria are not self-sufficient and not reliable. Always use construction VisitSchedules.createCriteria().

```
class VisitScheduleService {

   def springSecurityService

   void run{
    SecUser currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser

    def upcomingVisitSchedules = VisitSchedules.createCriteria().list() {
       and {
          visit {
             le('startTime', new DateTime())
          }
          eq('user', currentUser)
       }
    }  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class VisitScheduleService {

   def springSecurityService

   void run{

    SecUser currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser

    def upcomingVisitSchedules = VisitSchedules.findAll {
            visit.startTime >= new DateTime() && users.contains(currentUser)
    }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response it helped a lot, here is how it looks now.

```
class VisitScheduleService {
    def springSecurityService
    void run{
        SecUser currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
        def upcomingVisits = VisitScheduleNotification.createCriteria().list(){
            and{
                visit{
                    ge('startTime', new DateTime())
                }
                users{
                    eq('id', user.id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have one question though:
Question: I was trying out the `'in'("users",user)` criteria method to look for the user in the property `static hasMany = [users: User]`

```
def upcomingVisits = VisitScheduleNotification.createCriteria().list(){
            and{
                visit{
                    ge('startTime', new DateTime())
               }
               'in'('users', user)
            }
        }
```

but couldn't achieve what I needed?

Answer (score 0):

```
class VisitScheduleService {
    def springSecurityService
    void run{
        SecUser currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
        def upcomingVisits = VisitScheduleNotification.createCriteria().list(){
            and{
                visit{
                    ge('startTime', new DateTime())
                }            
                'in'('users', [currentUser])
            }
        }
    }
}
```